# Android DialogFragment Viewmodel destroyed after dismiss problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have DialogFragment in which I show 2 buttons. One button is to submit API call (it executes function submitBonusDecision(). It goes like this:

```
 private fun submitBonusDecision(decision: Boolean) {
        BONUS_IDENTIFIER.argumentValue()?.let { it ->
            bonusViewModel.submitBonusDecision(decision, it)
        }
        
        dismiss()
    }
```

This code should call function bonusViewModel.submitBonusDecision() in my ViewModel and submit code. But here comes the problem. It looks to me that dismiss() is called before the API call is executed. I guess dismiss destroys DialogFragment and probably ViewModel together with it even before the API call is executed. Please tell me does this way of thinking makes sense to you.
Also if it does, can you give advice how to solve this problem in android? Whenever we have dialog or DialogFragment, we usually want to close it after the button click. How to solve this problem and succeed in doing the work even after dialog dismiss? Is it possible to do this in ViewModel?

Comment: you r just another victim of asynchronous code .  you should wait for `bonusViewModel.submitBonusDecision()` to complete since its an asynchronous call . You make `bonusViewModel.submitBonusDecision()` return a LiveData and Observe it once you get Success then only call `dismiss()` .

Comment: Scope your view model to something with a larger lifecycle, like an activity or application so that it doesn't get destroyed when dialog fragment is closed

Comment: I am agree with @ADM use `dismiss` in your `observer`

Comment: @ADM I like your answer it's very good. But I have one question. When I click submit, in my ViewModel I need to wait 5 seconds and then execute client.refresh() function. If I do it your way, this flow will not be user-friendly. The user would click on accept button and wait 5-6 seconds on the dialog to close. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Usually when you have a long running task you show progress bar on screen . That the way to handle the UX.  UI is up to you how and where you want to show the Progress bar or a Progress Dialogue .

Comment: @ADM I like your first comment and I think it could be helpful for other people to see it. If you want you can write an answer. I will accept and upvote it